# Confusing C syntax

Tags: c, syntax, memory-address

I encountered some code in a tutorial about buffer overflows.
It's a program that exploits a simple program that is vulnerable to a buffer overflow (if some stack protection mechanisms are turned off).

**My question is: what is the for loop doing? I mean the line within the for loop:**

```
*(void **)(buf + i) = addr;
```

Its a bit of a strange syntax that I haven't seen before, or maybe I have seen it but it just confuses me.

The idea of the program is that the buf is passed as argument to the vulnerable program and through a strcpy it will overwrite the return address on the stack such that it will run the shellcode that is passed in an environment parameter.

Thanks!

**The full code:**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *addr = (char *) 0xc0000000 - 4 - (strlen(VULN) + 1) - (strlen(&shellcode) + 1);
    char buf[768];
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i += sizeof(void *)) {
        *(void **)(buf + i) = addr;
    }

    char *params[] = { VULN, buf, NULL };
    char *env[] = { &shellcode, NULL };
    execve(VULN, params, env);
    perror("execve");

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C has a kind of *Treehorn type system*. For any object `x` of type `T`, you can pretend it's an object of a different type. To do so, you cast the address of the object. So, in steps:

1. `T x;` is an object of type `T`.
2. `&x` is the address of the object, it's of type `T *` – "pointer to `T`".
3. Now pretend this is a pointer to something else: `(U *)(&x)` – a "pointer to `U`", but it's the same value.
4. If we dereference that, we treat the object `x` as though it were a `U`: `*(U *)(&x)`

Now apply all this to `T = char`, `x = buf[i]` and `U = void *` in your code. Note that `&buf[i]` is identical to `buf + i`. Also note that `i` is incremented in strides of `sizeof(void *)` so that each round of the loop doesn't step on the memory touched by the previous rounds.

A word of warning: it is generally not allowed to treat one object as though it were one of a different type; this is *undefined behavior*. There are only some exceptions; e.g. you can treat an `int` as though it were an `unsigned int`, and you can treat any object `x` as though it were a `char[sizeof x]`. (None of these are the case in your code, which is not well-formed.)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on _"you can treat any object x as though it were a `char[sizeof x]`"_? And how could we treat an `int` as if it were `unsigned int`? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig: 1) `(char*)(&x)`, 2) `int n; *(unsigned int *)(&n) = 1;`. The latter is about *layout compatible* types, the former allows you to access the underlying representation of a type (e.g. for serialization).

Comment: @Unheilig: There should be many related posts here on SO. Search around for a bit.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks! What would be a more common (and allowed) way of copying a 4 byte pointer into a buffer?

Comment: @Maricruzz: Invert the approach: Don't treat bytes like objects; treat objects like bytes (hence the opening analogy). For example: `char const * pa = (char const *)(&addr); buf[i] = pa[0]; buf[i + 1] = pa[1];` etc, up to `sizeof addr`. Either in a loop, or `memcpy` is also fine (the compiler can do `memcpy` with static sizes very efficiently).

Comment: @Maricruzz: To be sure, all three approaches [produce identical machine code](http://pastebin.com/B5WnvHw9) on x86_64. So there's no excuse for not writing correct C :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, it calculates a value which will remain constant throughout the execution of the `for` loop:

```
0xc0000000 - 4 - (strlen(VULN) + 1) - (strlen(&shellcode) + 1)
```

Then, inside the `for` loop, it writes this constant value into every "4-byte entry" in the `buf` array:

```
buf[0...3] = the constant value
buf[4...7] = the constant value
buf[8...11] = the constant value
...
buf[764...767] = the constant value
```